# How to send response to a client from node.js custom server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using [Node-Soap](https://github.com/milewise/node-soap) library to call a external web-serivce from my node.js server, code is as shown below:

```
var http = require("http");
var soap = require("soap");
var url = 'http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?wsdl';
var args = {Celsius: '40'};

http.createServer(function(request,response) {
  response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/html"});
  response.write("<h1>Hello, Web!</h1>");
  soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) { 
    client.CelsiusToFahrenheit(args, function(err, result) {
      console.log(result); //This works
      response.write(result); //This doesn't print
    });
  });
  response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

I am able to call web-service successfully and able to get response. The problem is when I print the `result` using console.log() I am able to get output as:

```
{ CelsiusToFahrenheitResult: '104' }
```

But when I send it via response.write, I am not able to get any output, I will get blank values. I tried giving `result.toString()` and `JSON.stringify(result)` but still I am getting blank.

Can you please help me? Why I am able to print data using console.log but not using response.write?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should end the response only after your SOAP request is done (you're ending it immediately after creating the SOAP client, but it might take a while before the result of the SOAP request is available):

```
http.createServer(function(request,response) {
  response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/html"});
  response.write("<h1>Hello, Web!</h1>");
  soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) { 
    client.CelsiusToFahrenheit(args, function(err, result) {
      ...convert result to string-form, perhaps with JSON.stringify()...
      response.end(result);
    });
  });
}).listen(8888);
```

A few things to note:

- `response.end()` can take data as well, so no need (in this case) to use a separate `response.write()`;
- `end()` expects the data argument to be a string or a `Buffer`;

Comment: Thank you for your response, as per you I changed my code as `var s = JSON.stringify(result);response.end(s);` but still I am getting only Hello, Web! not result's value :(

Comment: That's strange; I don't have a SOAP server I can use, so I tested with `setTimeout` instead, and that works just fine. You did remove the old `response.end`, correct? (here's my test code: https://gist.github.com/robertklep/5434012)

Comment: Yes, I did remove it, but still no vain. How did you set time out? If possible can you please share that code?